# Add Product XML Amazon

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services

I have looked over a lot of different documents and am stumped.

From the schemas I cannot work out what elements I definitely need to provide to the SubmitFeed to add a new basic product to Amazon.

We used flat files previously and it doesn’t look like we actually sent that much information over (sku/price quantity etc). Im just struggling to understand what I need to provide for a basic product for example do I need to provide: ItemPackageQuantity

Thanks for any help

Clare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note: To add a product to Amazon, you must do the following (all POST to SubmitFeed - therefore THREE different posts)

1. Post FeedType: _POST_PRODUCT_DATA_ - Values SKU (that is all I required
2. Post FeedType: _POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_ (SKU / Quantity)
3. Post FeedType: _POST_PRODUCT_PRICING_DATA_ (SKU / StandardPrice if sale
   StartDate/EndDate/SalePrice)

Documentation here: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl.pdf